# Unexpected non-void return value in void function. How do I return a variable from a function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I return a double variable from a function?

```
class Api {
    func getCoordinates(latitude: Bool) -> Double {
        if (latitude) {
            let url = URL(string: "https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&sites=08155200&parameterCd=00065&siteStatus=all")!
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
                if let data = data {
                    let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: data)
                    let lat = (posts.value?.timeSeries?.first?.sourceInfo?.geoLocation?.geogLocation?.latitude)
                    return lat
                }
            }
            print(5)
//            return 5
        } else {
            print(3)
            return 3
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code returns:

```
Unexpected non-void return value in void function
```

I could always remove `return lat` but that would kind of defeat the purpose.

Comment: See other topics where they use `URLSession`.

Comment: You cannot _return_ anything from a function that gets its value asynchronously (unless you want to adopt the wonderful new `async` `await`). To do that, you would need to make time run backwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's a closure. [Async/await](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/) is coming very soon, but in the meantime, remember that `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is an async function. That means the completion handler/closure will be called at a later time.

So, instead of `return`, you'll need to add another completion handler.

```
class Api {
                                        /// add completion handler
    func getCoordinates(latitude: Bool, completion: @escaping ((Double) -> Void)) {
        if (latitude) {
            let url = URL(string: "https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&sites=08155200&parameterCd=00065&siteStatus=all")!
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
                if let data = data {
                    let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: data)
                    let lat = (posts.value?.timeSeries?.first?.sourceInfo?.geoLocation?.geogLocation?.latitude)
                    completion(lat) /// similar to `return lat`
                }
            }
            print(5)
        } else {
            print(3)
            completion(3) /// similar to `return 3`
        }
    }
}
```

Your old code probably looked something like this:

```
let returnedDouble = Api().getCoordinates(latitude: true)
print(returnedDouble)
```

Now, replace it with this:

```
Api().getCoordinates(latitude: true) { returnedDouble in
    print(returnedDouble)
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question but what would I put in `...`?

Comment: @ColinMiller edited my answer

Comment: "Async/await is coming very soon" You mean like yesterday? :)

Comment: @matt (: in my defense, Xcode 13 is still in beta and not available to everyone

Comment: Yes, it's unclear to me what we're even allowed to say.

Comment: What would I use for a completion handler?

Comment: @ColinMiller what do you mean?

Comment: Would I just leave it as is with `@escaping` or do something else?

Comment: @ColinMiller yeah, leave it as is.

Comment: Using `Api().getCoordinates(latitude: true) { returnedDouble in
                    print(returnedDouble)
                }` gives me the errors `Contextual closure type '() -> Double' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body` and `Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Double'`

Comment: @ColinMiller my bad. I mixed up the closure. Will edit my answer.

Comment: hmmm. I don't get any errors now but when I call the function with `struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View{
        Text("Hello")
            .onAppear() {
                Api().getCoordinates(latitude: true) { returnedDouble in
                    print(returnedDouble)
                    let x = returnedDouble
                    print(x)
                }
        }
    }
}` it doesn't seem to return/print anything.

Comment: @ColinMiller then `if let data = data {` is most likely failing (data is nil).

Comment: I thought so too but when I ran it with this `if (latitude) {
            let url = URL(string: "https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&sites=08155200&parameterCd=00065&siteStatus=all")!
            print(url)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
                print(5)
            }
        }` it didn't print 5 as I requested because it was in the URLsession bit. How do I fix this?

Comment: @ColinMiller maybe ask another question - this shouldn't be related to the `Unexpected non-void return value in void function` error