# I can't seem to create a data string from OpenSky-network

Tags: json, swift, api

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to create a URLSession to download the data from OpenSky into a data string. I have the 2 print statements in there for debugging.

```
   let skyURL = "https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?lamin=35&lomin=-114&lamax=37&lomax=-112"

func performSkyRequest(urlString: String){
    
    if let url = URL(string: urlString){
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            if let safeData = data {
                let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
                print(safeData)
                print(dataString)
            }
        }
   
        task.resume
    }
}
performSkyRequest(urlString: skyURL)
```

Comment: Hint: Asynchronous process

Comment: I just answered a question that's almost the exact same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67896643/14351818)